# jQuery run through multiple if statements then continue

Tags: jquery, if-statement

just doing a little little sign up page, and im trying to make it check each field if it has a value if not it will add the class of .error but if all 3 inputs have a value then display the success page

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    //Check to see if the inputs have any data
    if ($('.username-input').val() == '') {
        $(this).addClass('error');
    }
    else if ($('.password-input').val() == '') {
        $(this).addClass('error');
    }
    else if ($('.email-input').val() == '') {
        $(this).addClass('error');
    }

    //if all inputs have data open up success page and close it.
    $(".btn").click(function() {
        $(".success-wrapper").animate({
            bottom: "0%"
        }, 'slow');
    });
    $(".close").click(function() {
        $(".success-wrapper").animate({
            bottom: "-100%"
        }, 'slow');
    })
});;
```

Comment: What if multiple fields have nothing? What is the code doing now? What is the desired behavior?

Comment: So what's your problem/question?

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started:

```js
/* javascript */
arr = ['username-input', 'password-input', 'email-input'];
err = false;

$(".btn").click(function() {
  err = false;
  $.each(arr, function(ndx, fld){
    $('.'+fld).removeClass('errorField');
    if ( $('.'+fld).val() == "" ){
      $('.'+fld).addClass('errorField');
      err = true;
    }
  }); //END $.each
  if (err) return false;
  $('.success-wrapper').fadeIn();
  $('.success-inner').animate({
    top : '20vh'
  },700,function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.success-inner').animate({
          top: '100vh'
        },700);
        $('.success-wrapper').fadeOut(500);
      },1500);
  });
}); //END .btn click
```

```css
/*  CSS  */
html,body{min-height:100vh;}
* {position:relative;box-sizing:border-box;}

.success-wrapper{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
  text-align:center;
  background:black;
  opacity:0.7;
  display:none;
}
.success-inner{
  top:100vh;
  width:30vw;
  height:80px;
  margin:0 auto;
  font-size:2rem;
  color:darkorange;
}
.errorField{background-color:yellow;}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="username-input" type="text" /><br>
<input class="password-input" type="text" /><br>
<input class="email-input" type="text" /><br>
<button class="btn">Submit</button>

<div class="success-wrapper">
  <div class="success-inner">Total Success</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't think `return false` inside `each` does what you expect it to. It only breaks the each loop. Doesn't return to outer click handler. Can see if you only enter one value you still get success in your snippet

Comment: Right you are...! Thanks, Charlie, for catching that. Updated

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to add new event listeners inside the first event handler. You only want to run the code inside the second `$(".btn").click` if you have values for all inputs.

This means you need to track if there are any errors.

You can also remove the code duplication by looping over your inputs and using `toggleClass()` since you also need to remove the error class (might do this in another event handler like blur though)

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    var isValidForm = true;
    $('.username-input,.password-input, .email-input').each(function(){
            var hasError = !this.value; 
            $(this).toggleClass('error', hasError);
            if(hasError){
               isValidForm  = false;
            } 
    });

     if(isValidForm){
        $(".success-wrapper").animate({
            bottom: "0%"
        }, 'slow');
     }

});

$(".close").click(function() {
    $(".success-wrapper").animate({
        bottom: "-100%"
    }, 'slow');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkInputs=function(){
    var isError=0;
      // Use an Each Loop to cycle through elements
      // Note that since these are classes, there could be more than three total
      // Consider using IDs
    $(".username-input, .password-input, .email-input").each(function(){
        if( $(this).val() == '' ){
            $(this).addClass('error');
            isError++;
        };
    });
      // If no errors, animate ".success-wrapper"
      // Note that you can chain .animate() and that the next effect won't occur
      //   until the last ends, unless the "queue" option is set to false
    if( isError == 0 ){
        $(".success-wrapper").animate({bottom:"0%"},"slow").animate({bottom:"-100%"},"slow");
    };
};

$(".btn").click(checkInputs);
$(".close").click(function(){
    $(".success-wrapper").animate({bottom:"-100%"},{duration:"slow",queue:"false");
});
```

You do not want to use the click handler inside the other click handler, this will not fire the event but add the event to the button's action list; then when you click the button again, the check event and the added event will fire.

The ".close" event was added, and I edited it so that it would stop any ongoing animations and start the "close" event.